# Insert spaces into a string with certain pattern JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I have a String input which looks smth like this:

```
a = "-5+++5"  ---> -5 +++ 5
b = "5                 ++    -5" ---> 5 ++ -5
c = "ABC        */ ZXC" ---> ABC */ ZXC 
d = "-XY**          XX" ---> -XY ** XX
```

essentialy string consists from 3 parts:
part1, part2 - integer or letters, probably with minus. and operation - some substring made of + - * /
I need to insert spaces around operation thing, so i will be able to get an List with split(" ")
My code is but it doesnt work(((

```
    string.replaceAll("(-?\\d+|\\D+)(?=[+\\-*/]+)", "$0 ");
```

and to get rid of exstra whitespaces

```
    string.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim()
```

Comment: Try `replaceFirst("^(-?\\w+)\\s*([/*+-]+)\\s*(-?\\w+)$", "$1 $2 $3")`

Comment: thanks, but it doesnt work with smth like this a+-b it gives a +- b and should give a + -b((

Comment: Ok, use `^(-?\w+)\s*((?:(?!-\b)[/*+-])+)\s*(-?\w+)$`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
^(-?\w+)\s*((?:(?!-\b)[/*+-])+)\s*(-?\w+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FsKNMX/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(-?\w+)` - Group 1 (`$1`): an optional `-` and then one or more word chars (`\p{Alnum}+` might be a better idea if you need to exclude `_`)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `((?:(?!-\b)[/*+-])+)` - Group 2 (`$2`): one or more `/`, `*`, `+`, `-` chars but the `-` char cannot be followed with a word char
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(-?\w+)` - Group 3 (`$3`): an optional `-` and then one or more word chars (or `\p{Alnum}+`)
- `$` - end of string

In Java:

```java
String result = text.replaceFirst("^(-?\\w+)\\s*((?:(?!-\\b)[/*+-])+)\\s*(-?\\w+)$", "$1 $2 $3");
```

Comment: thank you very much, i've sligtly modified this and it worked out how i wanted!